# Ionic 5 Capacitor FileTransfer

Tags: ionic-framework, angular9, capacitor, ionic5

I'm running in the browser an `ionic 5` APP using capacitor and I'm trying to use the file transfer functionality. I follow the documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer and configure my app using capacitor. Thus running:

```
npm install cordova-plugin-file-transfer
npm install @ionic-native/file-transfer
ionic cap sync
```

In my app.module, I registered the providers:

```
import { FileTransfer } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';

...
providers: [
        StatusBar,
        SplashScreen,
        ...
        FileTransfer,
        File
    ],
```

Note that I also installed the native file package, so in total I have the following 4 new packages:

```
"@ionic-native/file": "^5.27.0",
"@ionic-native/file-transfer": "^5.27.0",
"cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
"cordova-plugin-file-transfer": "^1.7.1",
```

My code in the component is:

```
import { Input, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FileTransfer, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-order-detail-order-card',
    templateUrl: './order-detail-order-card.page.html'
})
export class OrderDetailOrderCardPage {
    @Input() pdfUrl: string;
    @Input() orderCardId: string;

    constructor(private transfer: FileTransfer, private file: File) { }

    public downloadFile(): void {
        const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
        fileTransfer.download(this.pdfUrl, this.file.applicationDirectory + `${orderCardId}.pdf`).then((entry) => {
          console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
        }, (error) => {
          // handle error
        });
    }
}
```

When I run the app in the browser, I get the following warning and I'm not sure whether the file should donwload somewhere?

```
common.js:284 Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
```

Even if I don't get the file, I would be expecting to see the "download complete" message. It's not very clear to me as to whether I have to configure something else in my app to be able to run it locally or I have to use this functionality ONLY in either the emulator or the device itself.

What else needs to be configured to get this to work?

Comment: Capacitor doesn’t support cordova plugins on browser

Comment: common.js:284 Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available....... this comes because you run app in web browser. Run it emulator and check it using dev-tool. This warning is gone.

Comment: Hi @carlos, Are you able to download files?

Answer (score 0):

```
common.js:284 Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to include cordova.js or run in a device/simulator
```

this means that you are using the browser emulator which doesn't have any splashscreen, you can totally ignore that warning ( you won't get it using a simulator or a real device).

You should paste the html section of that page too, because probably the download doesn't start because an incomplete url and it doesn't proceed with the "then()"

maybe i'm wrong, but it can be possible.